# How to Group by Day with Ruport / Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reporting, ruport

I'm trying to evaluate Ruport for use in my Rails app, but am not sure how to take a series of records with date/time stamps and group them via Ruport's grouping functions.

I'm open to other/better methods to do this same grouping if Ruport doesn't make sense.

Comment: did you decide to go without ruport for this?  I'd like to be able to do this with ruport

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without ruport:

```
<% @posts.group_by {|p| p.created_at.at_beginning_of_day }.each do |day, posts| %>
  <h2><%= day.strftime("something...") %></h2>

  <% posts.each do |post| %>
    do stuff with `post`.
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Use `at_beginning_of_month`, `at_beginning_of_week` and so on, depending on what you want to group by.

Comment: This helped me to much right now. Thanks! I wish I could upvote it a few more times.

Answer (score 2):

Ruport includes a method to add a new column to a table. So date wise grouping from a timestamp source can be done like this:

```
@table.add_column('created_at_date') { |r| r.created_at.to_date }
created_at_date_grouping = Grouping(@table, :by => "created_at_date")
```

This method can, of course, also be used to generate more interesting reports like on Google Analytics:

```
@table.add_column('day_of_week') { |r| r.created_at.strftime('%a') }
@table.add_column('hour_of_day') { |r| r.created_at.strftime('%H') }
```

Don't know about performance though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving the @posts.group_by function into the controller rather than the view.